# Convert Angular 14 app into salesforce (VFpage or LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, angular

I have an angular(14) application with user login and data send to salesforce. Now have to change it into salesforce application (either VFpage or LWC) and upload it to community for salesforce users.

Q1: Salesforce app should be normal vf-page or bolt app or other?

Q2: How to convert the angular app into salesforce (need help)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Salesforce app should be normal vf-page or bolt app or other?

You probably don't want a Lightning Bolt Solution, but you can easily embed an Angular app inside Visualforce, Aura, and Lightning Web Components with virtually no effort. Without knowing more about your app or more specific details about what you're trying to do, all I can really say is: "yes, you can use a variety of options within Salesforce."

> Q2: How to convert the angular app into salesforce (need help)?

The specifics will depend on which technology you decide to use, but they will all have the same general principle. This requires just a few steps.

First, build the Angular app as a normal app. Next, take the entire `dist` folder (or wherever the binaries are saved to), and compress it into a ZIP file. After that, upload this file as a [Static Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources.htm&type=5). You may need to use two or more bundles if the file size exceeds 5MB. Check out the documentation for how to [build Angular apps](https://angular.io/guide/build).

Once you have the files upload, it's simply a matter of importing it into the appropriate container. In Visualforce, it should be as simple as a `script` tag. In Aura, you need to use [`ltng:require`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) to load the script. In Lightning Web Components, you need to use [`lightning-platform-resource-loader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) to load the app.

Finally, you just deploy the component you created in a Community, and it should work.